# How to get __radd__ to work with numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, math, numpy

Consider the following python code:

```
class MyClass:
   def __radd__(self, a):
      print "foo", a
      return a

p = MyClass()
```

To evoke radd the following can be run:

```
>>> print "bar"+p
foo bar
bar
```

This is the expected behavior. `__add__` is run and fails, therefore `__radd__` takes over and handles the situation.
But with numpy arrays it behaves a little differently:

```
>>> v = np.arange(2)
>>> print v+p
foo 0.
foo 1.
[0. 1.]
```

It seems that unlike the example above`v.__add__` itterativly goes through `v`'s components and performes `p.__radd__` on them. In other words it has decided that the returning type will be an `ndarray` (as long as the code don't crash). I get that this is numpy that tries to be smart, but somtimes I would like my class to handle the aritmethics.

Is it possible to get standard `__radd__` behavior with numpy arrays?

Answer (score 2):

When you do `a+b`, a normally gets first crack at defining what that means: `b.__radd__` will only be used  if `a.__add__` isn't implemented. So, in the general case, if you want to control addition, you have to make sure you put your object first: `b+a`.

According to [the docs](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__radd__), though, there's an exception to that. If you subclass `numpy.ndarray`, and define an `__radd__` method, that gets tried first. So, if it makes sense for your object to be based on an array, you can do that.

Comment: It makes a quite a bit of sense.

Comment: It creates a new problem though. The subsetting creates an error on initiation: `TypeError: requires argument 'shape' (pos 1) not found`. Customizing the `__init__` is my first thought, but to no use. Is there a way to get around this (for example through hacking of `__new__`)?

Comment: I don't know exactly how numpy works, but it might be that overriding `__new__` will do the trick.

Comment: Yes it is. I found the docs:
[link](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.subclassing.html)
Thank you for your input.