# I hace issue with __radd__ with format < ndarray> + <my object>

Tags: python, multidimensional-array

I'm a beginner in Python.

I try to understand the behavior of ****add**** and ****radd**** by a short test code with my class Point.

I want use the addition < + > in différent formes like :

1. Point + int
2. Point + float
3. Point + str        if it's possible to translate into int or float
4. Point + ndarray

With def_add_( )  methode in my class'code, it's good, I don't have issue for each cases

BUT !!! With def_radd_( )  method in code , I obtain a strange issue only for
ndarray + Point

my code

```
import numpy as np
class Point():
    def __init__(self, x = 0.0, y = 0.0, z = 0.0):
        self.point = np.array([x*1.0, y*1.0, z*1.0])

    def valeur(self):
        return self.point

    def __str__(self):
        return f"point : {self.point}"

    def __add__(self, other):
        #it's OK
        pass

    def __radd__(self, other):
        print( "__radd__  >>> self = ", self, "  other = ", other,end = '')
        if isinstance(other, np.ndarray ):
            print("<array>   + <Point> ", end = '' )
            a = self.point + other*1.0
            return Point(a[0], a[1], a[2]) 

        elif isinstance(other, int):
            print("   therefore we are in case <int> + <Point> we use __radd__  ", end = '' )
            a = self.point + other*1.0
            print(a)
            return Point(a[0], a[1], a[2])

        # elif other cases for str and float . The booth run whele

        else:
            return self.point

if __name__ == "__main__":
    point1 = Point( -1, 2, 1)
    print(point1)
    print("\nwhith the format np.array( [10, 20, 30 ] ) + point1.valeur() it's OK but it's not my target")
    print(np.array( [10, 20, 30 ] ) + point1.valeur())
    print("\nwhith the format ndarray + Point it's NOK. I obtain 3 calls of __radd__ for each elements of ndarray")
    print( "\n result IT'S NOT OK  ==> \n", np.array( [10, 20, 30 ] ) + point1 )
```

The output is :

```
 point : [-1.  2.  1.]

 whith the format np.array( [10, 20, 30 ] ) + point1.valeur() it's OK but it's not my target
 [ 9. 22. 31.]

 whith the format ndarray + Point it's NOK. I obtain 3 calls of __radd__ for each elements of ndarray

 __radd__  >>> self =  point : [-1.  2.  1.]   other =  10   therefore we are in case <int> + <Point> we use __radd__  [ 9. 12. 11.]

 __radd__  >>> self =  point : [-1.  2.  1.]   other =  20   therefore we are in case <int> + <Point> we use __radd__  [19. 22. 21.]

 __radd__  >>> self =  point : [-1.  2.  1.]   other =  30   therefore we are in case <int> + <Point> we use __radd__  [29. 32. 31.]

 result IT'S NOT OK  ==>  
 [<__main__.Point object at 0x00000214E00BBA30>
  <__main__.Point object at 0x00000214E00E5EB0>
  <__main__.Point object at 0x00000214EEDC3C40>]
```

The list of 3 address are in relation respectively with [ 9. 12. 11.], [19. 22. 21.] and [29. 32. 31.]

I was surprised:  I was thinked that the used test will be true : if isinstance(other, np.ndarray ):

**My question is** : Why the left ndarray give each element instead an full ndarray

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get \_\_radd\_\_ to work with numpy arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6127550/how-to-get-radd-to-work-with-numpy-arrays)

Comment: Thank you ! My problem is not how to use __add__ and __radd__
My problem is in the non-commutativity of the operator <+> between np.ndarray and my object <Point>
Tueda gave me the solution. I did not know the __array_ufunc__ method which allows to modify the <+> operator of the np.ndarray object. It's really interesting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ndarray` of NumPy is a bit special class that implements `ndarray` + `object` for **any** objects, which has a priority than your `ndarray` + `Point` by `Point.__radd__`. To change this behaviour, You need

```py
    # Add this method to class Point.
    def __array_ufunc__(self, ufunc, method, *args, **kwargs):
        if len(args) == 2 and len(kwargs) == 0:
            x = args[0]
            y = args[1]
            if isinstance(x, np.ndarray) and isinstance(y, Point):
                if ufunc is np.add:
                    return y.__radd__(x)
        return NotImplemented
```

See https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.classes.html.

Comment: point : [-1.  2.  1.]

__radd__  >>> self =  point : [-1.  2.  1.]   other =  [10 20 30]<array>   + <Point> 
 result is OK NOW  ==>  point : [ 9. 22. 31.]